# MongoDB "service" on clean Redhat can not be started

Tags: rhel, services, daemon, mongodb

I just bring up `Redhat 6.5 64-bit` from AWS and did the below things:

- Disabled SELinux
- Disabled Iptables
- All ports opened in Security Group
- Rebooted

Then i just followed, both of the below instructions:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat-or-centos/

I tried the both Links separately after clean installations again.

Here is the version:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# mongod --version
db version v2.6.4
2014-08-19T04:35:58.234-0400 git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910
```

**THEN HERE IS THE PROBLEM**:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# service mongod start
Starting mongod:                          [FAILED]
```

And here are the logs:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.669-0400 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2014-08-19T04:30:07.671-0400 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2014-08-19T04:30:07.671-0400 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

This is quite a very clean installation.
What is happening please.

Note:

```
[root@www.example.com ~]# ll /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mongod mongod 0 Aug 19 04:32 /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock
```